# .htaccess file not working at all

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect anyone when he is trying to hit "192.168.21.3:8080/ping" to "192.168.21.3:8080/ping.php" via creating a .htaccess file with following code in it:

```
//301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 http://192.168.1.234:8080/ping http://192.168.1.234:8080/ping.php
```

Also, following line in httpd.conf has been un-commentated:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

i am still learning the basics myself however i will have a try to help you out, If you let me know how you get on.. i can re-edit my answer should the solution not work.

You can either redirect all traffic to the page named ping.php or as per your question you can redirect a specific IP address to ping.php.

add the code below to your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 192\.168\.21\.3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ping\.php$
RewriteRule $ /ping.php[R=301,L]
```

Alternatively you could take a look here as this may also help you out:  https://perishablepress.com/permanently-redirect-a-specific-ip-request-for-a-single-page-via-htaccess/

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, the problem is that even though i have added the .htaccess file to root directory, still .htaccess file is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood the question the ip written is mine own machine's ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
RedirectMatch ^/ping$ http://192.168.1.234:8080/ping.php
```

to your www-root `.htaccess`. Nothing more.

Comment: Should, i add it to .htaccess file only??

Comment: Yes, to the `.htaccess`, placed in the `DocumentRoot` directory.

Comment: by DocumentRoot, you mean the root directory of webpage. If so, still not working

Comment: I've just tested this redirect and it worked for me. Check if you have `AllowOverride all` directive in your `httpd.conf`.